# How to retrieve data which has not been put into the cross-table, in MS Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I’ve got 3 tables:

- Channel(id),
- Content(id),
- Post(id, channel_id, content_id).

Post holds information about content posted via specified channel.

How to get all the pairs content-channel which are not in Post table in MS Access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `cross join` and then filter out the ones that exist:

```
select co.id, co.id
from channel as ch,
     content as co
where not exists (select 1
                  from post as p
                  where p.channel_id = ch.id and p.content_id = co.id
                 );
```

Well, MS Access doesn't support `CROSS JOIN` syntax, so you have to use a comma for this.

Answer (score 1):

You could obtain the result using a `left join` e.g.:

```
select q.ch, q.co
from 
    (select t.id as ch, u.id as co from channel t, content u) q 
    left join post p on q.ch = p.channel_id and q.co = p.content_id
where p.id is null
```

Here, the subquery uses a [cross-join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Cross_join) (aka [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product)) to return all combinations of the Channel ID & Content ID, and the outer query then returns those combinations which aren't present in the Post table by virtue of the `where` clause.